# Apply jQuery plugin in title is present

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery pluging that I currently apply to a particular class

```
$(".myClass").myPlugin({ ... });
```

Currently it will apply it to any `<th>` in my table that has the class **.myClass**

How can I re-write the code to call that plugin if the class is present **and** `<th>` has the **title** attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(".myClass[title]")` should do it.

Edit:  After your edit, if you specifically want `th` elements, use `$("th.myClass[title]")`

Answer (score 1):

Use the JQuery selector `$(".myClass[title]")` to find the elements you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".myClass[title=MyTitle]").myPlugin({...});
```